# Retrive All Fulfillment Orders Of A Specified Order

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I want to get all fulfillmentOrders of an order using rest api as below in NestJS application:

```
async getFulfillmentOrders(orderId: string) {
    const res = await this.shopify.rest.FulfillmentOrder.all({
      session: this.getSession(),
      order_id: orderId,
    });

    return res?.fulfillment_orders;
  }
```

the  response contains an object that has a field called data with an empty array value and has headers field.
when I paste url of the order in route with /fulfillment_orders.json it returns the expected fulfillment orders. but with calling rest api returns the mentioned data.

when I go to the below url it gives the response:
https://.shopify.com/store//orders/orderId/fulfillment_orders.json

all secret keys and all other stuff to connect with shopify are set and there is not any problem with it.
I use @shopify/shopify-api package to call shopify rest api

Answer (score 0):

after struggling with the mentioned problem. the way of getting fulfillmentOrders we should add 'write_merchant_managed_fulfillment_orders' and 'read_merchant_managed_fulfillment_orders' to scopes of api.

Comment: I don't think you need write scope if you just want to retrieve them.